# Prove that certain convergence in distrubution implies expectation convergence.

Tags: probability

Consider

- $\forall n$, $X_{n1},X_{n2},...,X_{nl_n}$ independent such that $E[X_{nl}]=0$ and
  $$S_n:= \sum_{l=1}^{l_n} X_{nl}$$
- uan proporty: $$\,\,\,\max_{1\leq l \leq l_n} P[|X_{nl}|> \epsilon] \to 0, \,\, \forall \epsilon>0$$
- $var(S_n) = \sum_{l=1}^{l_n} var(X_{nl}) \leq C$, $\forall n$

Suppose that $S_n \to^d S$. I want to show that $$E(S)=0 $$
Note that $E(S_n)=0, \,\,\ \forall n.$

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_n\to S$ in distribution and $\sup_n ES_n^{2} <\infty$ implies that $(S_n)$ is uniformly integrable and $ES_n \to ES$. Ref: A Course in Probability Theory by K L Chung, Theorem 4.5.2.

Comment: Kavi, according your reference I can show that the expectations are convergent to $ES$. But it is not true for variances, unless the third moments bound uniformly. Do you know other ways to achieve  the convergence of variances: $var(S_n)\to var(S)$.??